# How to change value of control inside pivot datatemplate on listpicker_selectedIndexChagned event

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

```
<phone:Pivot Title="Bank" x:Name="pivotBank" 
                 ItemsSource="{Binding PivotItems}">
        <phone:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding StrBankName}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </phone:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
        <phone:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="listPickerAccountNumber" SelectionChanged="listPickerAccountNumber_SelectionChanged"
                                            ItemsSource="{Binding listAccountDetails}" >
                            <toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding StrAccountNumber}" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
                            <toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding StrAccountNumber}" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
                        </toolkit:ListPicker>
                        <TextBlock Text="Account Detail"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Name="textBlockAccountNumber" Text="{Binding StrAccountNumber}"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Name="textBlockBalance" Text="{Binding DblBalance}"></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </phone:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
    </phone:Pivot>
```

Above pivot control contains headers as bank names and pivot datatemplate contains list of accounts. I want to change the control values of textBlockAccountNumber and textBlockBalance on SelectedIndexChanged event of listPicker.
My question is, is there any way to find control by name from the pivot. I used INotifyPropertyChanged Interface and implemented event with handler but not able to get the rid of it.

Comment: You already using `DataBinding` here. So instead of changing corresponding `TextBlock`'s value, you should change the underlying model's property value. If you've implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` and used it properly, changes in the model will automatically reflected in the UI.

Comment: Thanks for reply, INotifyPropertyChanged was implemented properly but somehow the collection which was supposed to change was not able to reflect the properties. I got the rid of it and i got it working.